# Terraform: Reference to undeclared input variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have such structure for Terraform:
Three modules (app, db, vpc) and two directories (prod, stage)

```
├── modules
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ├── db
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   └── vpc
│       ├── main.tf
│       └── variables.tf
├── prod
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── outputs.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfstate
│   └── variables.tf
├── stage
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── outputs.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfstate
│   └── variables.tf
```

When I launch Terraform from "stage" or "prod" directories and input a variable:

```
terraform/prod - (main) > terraform plan
var.cluster_name
  Enter a value: prod
```

Then, I received an error that variable is not set up:

```
│ Error: Reference to undeclared input variable
│ 
│   on ../modules/app/main.tf line 47, in resource "google_compute_address" "app_ip":
│   47:   name    = var.cluster_name

│ An input variable with the name "cluster_name" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a
│ variable "cluster_name" {} block.
```

Could somebody help, what is the issue? How to set up variable properly, to be seen in all modules from selected project?

Comment: I assume that you are calling your ../modules/app/main.tf module within prod/main.tf - check if you're passing the variable explicitly to the module. Keep in mind that child modules won't just inherit variables from their parent modules.

Answer (score 1):

I find the issue:
file main.tf in each project (/prod and /stage) must define variable like a function:
**cluster_name = var.cluster_name** - it was missing
cluster_name in module is isolated variable and it must be defined "in function", here is config:

```
module "app" {
  source = "../modules/app"
  cluster_name = var.cluster_name
}

module "db" {
  source = "../modules/db"
  cluster_name = var.cluster_name
}

module "vpc" {
  source = "../modules/vpc"
  cluster_name = var.cluster_name
}
```